# Array from recursive call being overwritten

Tags: java, recursion, multidimensional-array, sudoku, recursive-backtracking

We're making a program to solve an asterisk sudoku via a recursive approach with back tracking.

The `solveIt` method calls the `solve` method which is the recursive method. `grid` is declared before to be a 9x9 2D array that contains the puzzle to be filled in. If there is one solution, the program must print out the completed puzzle however if there are more solutions it must only print out the number of possible solutions.

**Question is**: Inside of `solve`, `print();` works just fine and prints out the complete puzzle. However outside of the method it prints out the empty initial puzzle. Why is this? We cannot figure out why a separate variable (`h` in this case) also gets randomly overwritten when `solve` completes.

```java
int[][] h;
int solutionCounter = 0;

void solve() {
    int[] next = findEmptySquare();
    if (!(next[0] == -1 && next[1] == -1)) {
        if (grid[next[0]][next[1]] == 0) {
            for (int i = SUDOKU_MIN_NUMBER; i <= SUDOKU_MAX_NUMBER; i++) {
                if (!(givesConflict(next[0], next[1], i))) {
                    //fills in the puzzle
                    grid[next[0]][next[1]] = i;
                    //go to next number
                    solve();
                }
            }
            grid[next[0]][next[1]] = 0;
        }
    } else {
        //print(); here it works just fine
        solutionCounter++;
        h = grid.clone();
    }
}

void solveIt() {
    solve();
    if (solutionCounter > 1) {
        System.out.println(solutionCounter);
    } else {
        grid = h.clone();
        print(); //here it prints the empty puzzle
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

The `.clone()` method seems to simply reference `h` to `grid`. So `h` points to `grid` and takes on its values leading to the problem we were having above.

Therefore the following solution was implemented:

```java
//copy the grid into h.
for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
        h[x][y] = grid[x][y];
    }
}
```

More information on `clone()`:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/clone-method-in-java-2/